# Copying from a set of cells from one column and paste them in consecutive columns in VBA Excel Macros

Tags: excel, vba

I have got a set of values in Range 'A' and Range 'B'. I want to compare each consecutive row of Range 'A' and when the previous row is greater than the next row ; I want to copy then set of points below the compared points and paste them in the consecutive columns. for eg. C,G,J etc... I have got the compare  part  done ..Just the arranging part is taking my time. In my case I am trying to use DO Until and For Loop. But is there any better way ... PLs Advice...

```
 Range("H1").Select

 Do Until Range("H1", Range("H1").End(xlDown))

 If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then

 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
 j = 2

 For i = 1 To Range("H1", Range("H1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

 Cells(i + 1, 8).Select
 Selection.Copy
 Cells(i + 1, 11 + j).Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste

 Cells(i + 1, 9).Select
 Selection.Copy
 Cells(i + 1, 12 + j).Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste


 Next i

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select


 Else

 j = 0
 For i = 1 To Range("H1", Range("H1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

 Cells(i + 1, 8).Select
 Selection.Copy
 Cells(i + 1, 11 + j).Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste

 Cells(i + 1, 9).Select
 Selection.Copy
 Cells(i + 1, 12 + j).Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste

 Next i

 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

 End If



Loop
```

Comment: I have added the code which I am trying to work on

Comment: You can replace this Range("H1", Range("H1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count with a variable e.g. lastRow, j serves no purpose in the second For Loop as does not increment so can be removed.

Comment: Your code doesn't do any comparison other than an ISEMPTY test. It simply copies and pastes.